# How to pay back when the person you stole from refuse to take the money?

Tags: theft

Hei. Me and my sister bought a house together. We paid 100 000 each the rest was a loan we took together. We fixed the house so we both worked there by painting and on. The same day we was finished she locked me out of the house. I couldt go in. So she went to a lawer and made papers so that i can sign the house over to her. I refused. But i wanted to get a deal so i signed the papers but i wasent gonna give them to her until we make a deal. I trusted my mother and gave my mother the papers. I told my mother not to give them to her beacuse then she will take thd house. My mother said ok but she gave them to my sister and my mother says that she stole them from her. I made her call her and demand the papers back my sister said no. She gave me my 100000 minus a loan we took to fix the kitchen. I then realized that i lost house i stole some gold from her i sold it for 23000  she lived in the house for about ten years and sold it with a profit about 2 millions. Now 14 years later i give her the money for the gold but she refuse to take it beacuse she wants to be forgiven first. I dont want to forgive her unless she gives me my half of the profit. What do i do? Can she refuse to take the money when i try to make opp for my wrong?do i have to forgive her. She wants forgivness but dont want to give anything back.what does islam say about this. I want to pay back. She lived and paid for the house i paid for rent other place so in my opinion the house was mine also the hole time cuse i never agreed to give it to her. She stole it.

Answer (score 1):

if any of the loan you guys took and it had to do with interest even if it was one percent it would be haram
The Prophet, , said: "A dirham of riba which a man receives knowingly is worse than committing adultery thirty six times"

The forgiving each other part it is basically not a choice and since you guys are related to each other meaning sisters Islamically you guys have to try to figure out a way and forgive and have mercy towards each other

Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “It is not permissible for a man to forsake his Muslim brother for more than three days, each of them turning away from the other when they meet. The better of them is the one who gives the greeting of salaam first.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5727; Muslim, 2560).

and it is worse when you guys are related and a much bigger sin.I would recommend you and your sister to have a talk and figure out something and try to have mercy towards each other.
Abdullah ibn Amr (as) reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “The merciful will be shown mercy by the Most Merciful. Be merciful to those on the earth and the One in the heavens will have mercy upon you.”

Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 1924

the taking(stealing) the Gold part witch is a sin repent from that and be the bigger person and forgive your sister or else maybe the matter well not get fixed easily.And remember when you make repentance do it sincerely so that Allah swt well forgive you and we all should forgive others as quickly as you would expect Allah (the most high) to forgive us

dont get me wrong what your sister did was wrong of her and you should talk to her maybe in a conforting way and tell her to repent also